# Embed Keynotes slide into iPad app

Tags: ipad, powerpoint, keynote

Now my customer want me to put a keynote or powerpoint slides file into iPad app. It is an offline app.

No conversion from slides to video, and play it, which is not what we want.

They want to keep all transition and chart animation, and have UITab to go to every single slide.

Does anyone have same experience?

Thanks in advance.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Building a keynote or powerpoint presenter into your iPad app will be very tricky. The easiest (and possibly your best option) is to open the saved powerpoint/keynote file WITH the Keynote application, if the user has it installed on their device.

You will need to use the UIDocumentInteractionController class to do this. Here is an example on how to open a PDF in iBooks. You should be able to adapt this code to work with a powerpoint or keynote file.

http://andycodes.tumblr.com/post/738375724/ios4-sdk-opening-pdfs-in-ibooks

Comment: What if users don't have Keynote installed, is the way u provide stil working ?

Comment: It won't work if they don't have an application like Keynote to view them. You have 2 options: give them a link to the App Store to purchase it; or use the QuickLook framework to "preview" the presentation. The QuickLook framework will drop all animation, and render pages statically, but hey, at least the user will see them! 

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html

Comment: Oh!! You mean if I want users who dont have keynote installed to see our full-featured slides(transition and animation), I need to program from scratch. There is no perfect way that just 'convert and done'. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct. In order to build a presenter with full Keynote support, you would need to reverse engineering most of the Keynote application, which for a single developer (or small team of developers) could take years! If downloading the Keynote application is not a viable option, your best bet is to use the QuickLook framework. If you NEED all the transitions and effects, you'll need to save the Keynote as a movie on your Mac each time, and upload the video version instead of the Keynote file.